# How to get the screen position of Visual Studio UI Elements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension.

Is there any way to get the position of the IDE's UI Elements?

So for example I would need the screen coordinates of a toolbar item like the Run Application - Button.

As far as I see the corresponding UI Element Classes of the Visual Studio SDK do not provide any position properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio UI is WPF, so you can use [System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netframework-4.8) to enumerate and locate UI elements.